# "Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined" when starting vue application

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I have a project that's been running perfectly for a few months now, able to run `npm run serve` with no problem. I have to terminate and run the command again whenever I switch networks, but that has never been a problem and the server could always start again.

Until now - no matter what I do I can't get the server to start. I get this error:

```
npm run serve

> xbs@0.6.2 serve D:\workspace\[PROJECT]
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\[PROJECT]\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:667:47)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Server (D:\workspace\[PROJECT]\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:666:22)
    at serve (D:\workspace\[PROJECT]\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:137:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

The last time I got this message was when I forgot to set the `.env` files, but this is a previously working copy with all necessary files set, and **no changes since the last working run**.

I've even tried pulling a fresh copy of the repo, running `npm i` and setting all env files but it still fails.

`npm run lint` and `npm run build` can still work, only `npm run serve`.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: That line seems related to websocket proxies

Comment: @Phil I'm lost - what do I do to fix it?

Comment: What's in your `vue.config.js` file?

Comment: @Phil thanks for the hints - `devServer.proxy` in my vue config was indeed trying to access a no longer existent env variable. Oddly enough this wasn't a problem for the past week or so since I removed that variable, but removing the reference to the variable solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The newest webpack-dev-server version detects this and skips the proxy target. Made a PR here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/3647 to warn the user.

Comment: In my case I forgot to even define a .env file. This can also cause " ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined". So ".env" and vue.config.js must be checked for env variables and the env file's existence itself.

Answer (score 26):

The problem was again with the .env files. My `vue.config.js` was trying to access a previously set environment variable that had since been removed.

Only strange thing was that there weren't any problems up til now?

Comment: I'm sure this saved me a hour of debugging. I had devServer settings in vue.config.js that messed it up for me.

Answer (score 5):

I guess your devServer.proxy.target is empty! 
You could set this configuration

Answer (score 3):

For me it was that I forgot to create (or copy from another PC) the .env file after clone and try to run my project on another PC.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.

I used in the project `process` to get the backend address(for example):

```js
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api/back/*': {
        target: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL,
        pathRewrite: {
          '/api/back': '/api/back',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

But there was no `.evn` file.

Just create `.env` file:

```
VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL= 0.0.0.0:2222 #example
```

Didn't notice the answer [@Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596688/sergey).

Answer (score 0):

I declared this environment variable in `.env.dev`, but the local build failed, and the same project ran without problems, so I created a new `.env` file and declared it in it

```js
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: process.env.VUE_APP_PROXY,
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happend to me, i delete the .env =/. After create again resolve